# XCUITest with Simulator stop working on MAC M1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, apple-m1, xctest, xcuitest

[image]

Testing XCUITest on a Macbook Pro runs smoothly, but when I try to run the test on a Macbook Air M1, it fails.
During the test, the simulator stopped working and I saw a black screen.
what should i do. Thank you

It occurred when I launched the app's test suites.
I try on xcode 13 and 14
Simulator : IpadGen9 ios15.5 and 16.0